# Selectively sum elements of list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a list of float like this one:

```
00000.0001
00000.0002
00000.0003
00000.0004
00001.0009
12345.0015
12345.0016
12345.0017
12345.0018
12345.0019
12346.0010
54321.0021
54321.0022
54321.0023
```

My goal is to sum the first and last elements of a each group within a range, in my case if it's plus 1 maximum, for example:

```
00000.0001 + 00001.0009
12345.0015 + 12346.0010
54321.0021 + 54321.0023
```

I'm trying to iterate the array using zip and range based on the length of the array, storing the first element of the group first, but cannot quite nail the solution.

I don't know much abound pandas, but would that help? Any other tip would be appreciated, don't necessarily need the exact solution.

Comment: are these strings? `00000.0001` doesn't look like a valid float.

Comment: It's also not clear what *exactly* your range is. You said "plus 1 maximum" but `1.0009` is more than `0.0001 + 1.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just iterate over the list and keep track of how often you cross the threshold. Keep track of the value when you last crossed it and add them together.

```
things = [1,2,3,4,10,11,12,21,22,23]
start = things[0]
threshold = 10
totals=[]

for i, n in enumerate(things):
    if n - start  >= threshold:
        totals.append(start+things[i-1])
        start = n

if start != n:
    totals.append(start+n)
else:
    totals.append(n)
   
      
print(totals)
assert sum(totals) == (1+10)+(11+12)+(21+23)
```

Comment: the OP want to add the first and last element withing the threshold, no the last two

Comment: This adds the first element within the nth threshold and the last element in the n-1th threshold,    it's the same just different. What we do with the last group if we never cross the threshold is undefined.. they probably want to add things[-1] to the total

Comment: isn't the same, in your example for the first threshold you add 11+10, but the op seem to want 11+1, and that obviously isn't the same

Comment: @Copperfield that's why `total = start` 1+(10+11)+(12+21) ==   (1+10)+(11+12)+(21)  .. as I say what to do with that hanging group at the end is ill-defined.. it's an exercise for the reader to make it fit by handling the last case however they want to.

Comment: I've changed it to close the last group out if there is one.  If the last group is a single element it will be added once (not the start AND end of the group, being identical) more likely what is required.

Comment: ah, I see, that make sense. But looking at OP example, it seem to me that it want a list of the sum per threshold group [(1+10),(11+12),(21+23)], not the accumulative sum of those

Comment: @Copperfield could make it do that with little effort.  We have 'Start' and 'Current' value at the same time so could append the result of those to a list instead.

Comment: @Copperfield you're right, and as that option solves for both solutions (via sum()) I changed it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use zip to identify the elements that are at more than 1.0 (threshold) away from their predecessor.  Applying a cumulative sum on these   breaks will produce group identifiers that can then be used with groupby():

```
L = [0.0001,
0.0002,
0.0003,
0.0004,
1.0009,
12345.0015,
12345.0016,
12345.0017,
12345.0018,
12345.0019,
12346.0010,
54321.0021,
54321.0022,
54321.0023]

from itertools import groupby,accumulate

threshold = 1.0
groups = accumulate(b-a>threshold for a,b in zip(L[:1]+L,L))
result = [ (g[0],g[-1]) for g,g[:] in groupby(L,lambda _:[next(groups)]) ]

print(result)           
[(0.0001, 0.0004), 
 (1.0009, 1.0009),           # 1.0009 - 0.0004 = 1.0005 > 1.0
 (12345.0015, 12346.001), 
 (54321.0021, 54321.0023)]
```